# Unresolvable symbols in @Entity annotation

Tags: android, android-room

I'm trying to implement a database using Room and have issues defining foreign keys. Inside the @Entity parameters, `arrayOf`, `entity` and `onDelete` are all highlighted in red and the popup says the symbol or method can't be resolved. If I try building anyway, I get two errors;

`error: method references are not supported in -source 1.7
(use -source 8 or higher to enable method references)`

and

`error: class, interface, or enum expected`

I tried resolving the unrecognised method `arrayOf` by taking Android Studio's suggestion of importing `com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.arrayOf` but then an odd 'componentType:' highlight appears before each field so I suspect this isn't the right `arrayOf`

Looking at docs and other source isn't helping- there's either no use of foreign keys or I see no difference between what I'm looking at and what I have in my code. Does anybody know have an idea what I'm missing?

The entity definition I'm working with is

```
package uk.co.craiggraham.spotifysandpit1.database;
//import android.arch.persistence.room.Entity;
//import android.arch.persistence.room.ForeignKey;
//import android.arch.persistence.room.Index;
import android.arch.persistence.room.*;

import static android.arch.persistence.room.ForeignKey.CASCADE;

@Entity(foreignKeys = arrayOf(ForeignKey(
        entity = Playlist::class,
        parentColumns = arrayOf("id"),
        childColumns = arrayOf("PlaylistID"),
        onDelete = CASCADE
)))

public class PlaylistTrack {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private long id;

    private long TrackID;

    public PlaylistTrack() {
    }
}
```

build.gradle is

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "uk.co.craiggraham.spotifysandpit1"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    // This library handles authentication and authorization
    api 'com.spotify.android:auth:1.0.0-alpha'

    // This library handles music playback
    api 'com.spotify.sdk:spotify-player-24-noconnect-2.20b@aar'

    // This is for accessing the Spotify server for playlist management
    api 'com.github.kaaes:spotify-web-api-android:0.4.1'

    //For database stuff
    def room_version = "1.1.1"

    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$room_version"
    // Test helpers
    testImplementation "android.arch.persistence.room:testing:$room_version"


}
```

Comment: Could it be that you're looking at a tutorial which uses Kotlin in your Java project?

Comment: Aaaaaah.... ironically I was just reading about that, having only just heard about it, and thinking it'd be a good idea to have a play. Yes, further down beyond where I'd looked is a "fun" keyword.